# Reading a GZip compressed AVRO file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gzip, avro

I have a bunch of AVRO files which I've compressed externally using GZip.
I'm trying to read them in Ruby without decompressing them, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it:

```ruby
require 'avro'

def open_avro(file)
  if file =~ /avro$/
    Avro::DataFile.open(file)
  elsif file =~ /avro\.gz$/
    begin
      $/ = ""
      file = Zlib::GzipReader.open(file)
      reader = Avro::IO::DatumReader.new(file, nil)
      file.rewind # we need to rewind because DatumReader seeked thefile
      avro   = Avro::DataFile::Reader.new(StringIO.new(file.gets), reader)
    end
    return avro
  end
end
```